JQuery autocomplete from DB in spring boot and Thymeleaf
this is my template:
  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-kmHvs0B+OpCW5GVHUNjv9rOmY0IvSIRcf7zGUDTDQM8="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.11.8/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" >
    $( function() {
      $( "#hint" ).autocomplete({
        source: "https://api.nunyito.com/api/geoDetailsForWeb",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          alert('hi');
          this.value = ui.item.value;
          console.log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
          return false;
        }
      });
    } );
  </script>

..

<form  th:action="@{/alarmNotification/save}" th:object="${data}" method="post">
              <p >
                <label for="title">
                </label><input id="title" type="text" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Title"/>
                <label for="hint"></label><input type="text" id="hint" name="hint" />
              </p>
              </form>

..

but I have this errors:

I have the same error using:
<form  th:action="@{/alarmNotification/save}" th:object="${data}" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input id="title" name="title" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="email" />
    <label for="hint">Hint</label>
    <input id="hint" name="hint" />
  </div>
</form>

and I don't see the alert('hi') and it does not reach the server, either

The error can be caused by 2 things:
1 - Not adding all the necessary attributes, just like @Rap said
<form th:action="@{/alarmNotification/save}" th:object="${data}" id="formData" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input id="title" type="text" th:field="*{email}" name="title" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="email" />
    <label for="hint">Hint</label>
    <input type="text" id="hint" name="hint" autocomplete="on" />
  </p>
</form>

2 - Including the slim version of Jquery (Probable)
The slim version of Jquery doesn't have the Ajax Library,  which is required by the ".autocomplete()" function of jQuery UI. I know you're adding both versions, but this is probably a conflict between them, so just remove the slim version and try again:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.11.8/umd/popper.min.js"></script>


Change this:
<form  th:action="@{/alarmNotification/save}" th:object="${data}" method="post">
              <p >
                <label for="title">
                </label><input id="title" type="text" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Title"/>
                <label for="hint"></label><input type="text" id="hint" name="hint" />
              </p>
              </form>

To this:
<form  th:action="@{/alarmNotification/save}" th:object="${data}" id="form1" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input id="title" name="title" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="email" />
    <label for="hint">Hint</label>
    <input id="hint" name="hint" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
</form>

If you want autocomplete to not auto-fill, go autocomplete="off" instead.
If you don't want your form to have labels, delete the labels completely and add an aria-label to each <input>:
<input aria-label="Title" ... />


unfortunately I same error :-(

@NuñitoCalzada I updated my answer to add an id to the form and autocomplete to the hint input. Please try again.

@Rap, I'm curious - why did you remove the input type attribute?

@FiddlingAway type=text is the default for <input>s. So to add it is just more characters to be sent from server to client. Makes your page lighter to send to the client. It's not wrong to include it, but no need.
